# Why do all sounds work except DVD playback?

Tags: windows-7, audio, video, dvd, vlc-media-player

I've come across a strange issue and can't seem to fix it myself or find an answer online.

I have an HP tower running Windows 7. Absolutely every sound works on it except for when a DVD is inserted and played, then only the DVD has no sound at all. It doesn't matter which player I use (I've tried regular Windows Media Player, VLC, Quicktime, etc), there is no sound. All internet sounds work, iTunes plays back music and video such as movie previews, though interestingly playing music files through Quicktime, VLC, or Windows Media Player doesn't work either.

I've been through the speaker audio properties multiple times. All other audio devices (there is only one, a RealTek audio device) are disabled, though I tried with them enabled, too. I've reinstalled the driver after uninstalling and deleting all residual driver files from the HP website. I've tried VLC settings, uninstalling programs, virus scans, etc. The only thing I haven't tried is a fresh install and I would like to avoid that if possible.

So, is there anything else I can try? I am all out of ideas.

Comment: Does an audio CD play music from that drive? If not, the drive may be defective. When was the last time it worked?

Comment: It does, but once again depending on which application I open it with. If I use iTunes (the default for audio), there is no issue. But if I try to use one of the many applications that also play video, no sound at all. This issue is replicated whether the files come from a disc in the drive or they are files located on the hard drive, so I don't think it's the DVD drive itself.

Comment: @DavidPostill Modern DVD drives are plain SATA connections internally, last I checked (and I think that applies to laptop form factors too).  External readers are USB or FireWire usually.  In what recent era did CD Drives have dedicated audio connections?  (Not for the past decade at least)

Comment: @qualitech I know it's stupid and a long shot but did you verify the applications playing the audio or trying to aren't muted in the volume mixer?  I accidentally muted everything other than iTunes and ran into this recently when I forgot I muted everything as such...

Comment: @ThomasW. I'm guessing 30 years ago (showing my age again) :) http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/CD-ROM+audio+cable says before the mid 1990's

Comment: @DavidPostill Yeah that's obsolete.  It's a simple SATA connection for internal, or USB/FireWire typically for external drive readers.

Comment: @qualitech: "playing music files through Quicktime, VLC, or Windows Media Player doesn't work either" - Which format? Or do you mean irrespective of format no audio is played by any of these players?